# Can an extinct creature be a Patronus?

Tags: harry-potter, patronus-charm

A Patronus should form as an animal with which the summoner feels a "deep connection" that reflects their "innermost personality". But lots of people feel real passionate about extinct animals especially dinosaurs. If you really like stegosaurus, could your Patronus be a stegosaurus?

Comment: Given that Harry didn't know his father was an unlicensed animagus who changed into a stag at the time, I think the connection is made by some outside force. Therefore, if someone was suited to have a megalodon as their patronus, the universe might be cool with that.

Comment: What is meant by "*most* extinct"? When a species is extinct (i.e. not a single living specimen left), can it become any *more* extinct?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper idk, last time I asked a question about "can" instead of "most" it got locked for a day so I just used "most" again.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - I assumed they meant most *anciently* extinct. Mammoths only went extinct a few thousand years ago, as compared to dinos which went extinct 65 million years back.

Comment: *"Can an extinct creature be a Patronus"* would have been a fair question too. My answer wouldn't have changed one iota

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [*Wonderbook: Book of Spells*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Spells), extinct Patronuses are very rare. A wizard named [Hedley Fleetwood](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Hedley_Fleetwood) had a Patronus that took the form of a **woolly mammoth**.

[image]

Comment: It's very impressive that there is an actual answer to this one!

Comment: @ShaneHudson - [All my answers are impressive.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1wrSsIVqHpM)