# Is a Patronus an accurate recreation of an animal as it lived, or a depiction of the summoner's conception of that animal?

Tags: harry-potter, patronus-charm

According to [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/261870/150833), it is possible to have an extinct animal Patronus. But, nobody has a completely accurate scientific understanding of the appearance, behavior, sounds, etc. of long-extinct animals like the woolly mammoth or dinosaurs. So, is a Patronus like this accurate to how it was when it was actually alive? Or is it accurate to what the summoner thinks it was like when it was alive?

This extends to extant animals too. If for example the summoner didn't know something important about the animal but really liked that animal anyway. Like I probably couldn't tell you exactly how many toes any animal (except human) has off the top of my head; so if it was my Patronus would it have too many/too few toes?

Comment: "You may suspect, but you will never truly know what form your Patronus will take until you succeed in conjuring it." - Miranda Goshawk's overview of the Patronus Charm. Source: [harrypotter.fandom.com](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Patronus_Charm).  Based on all the info in the article, it is implied that it comes from our memories and possibly from the subconscious. Most of the "Patronuses" are familiar animals but rarely mythical or extinct animals. Let me know if this serves as an answer and I can try to expand a bit also.

Comment: I would buy that it comes from the subconscious, but what exactly is it coming out of there? Is it just the identity of the animal (i.e. this guy subconsciously identifies with dogs in general, magic picks a dog from the canonical dog patronus catalog) or the full package (i.e. this guy subconsciously identifies with his idea of a dog that looks, sounds, and acts exactly like he imagines)? If it's the former, where are the elements the summoner doesn't know coming from? If it's the latter, how far could it go off the rails (i.e. a six-legged dog)?

Comment: There isn't an exact explanation, however, you might say that the magic/spell extracts it from your mind/subconscious. "...corporeal Patronus, a guardian which generally takes the shape of the animal with whom they share the deepest affinity." It is very hard to fully conjure a Patronus and the full form usually appears when you really mean it and need it. "...the Patronus was the awakened secret self that lay dormant until needed, but which must now be brought to light". For example, in the movies, the students could conjure some not fully-formed animals. There are incorporeal ones also.

Comment: On Pottermore, the [add plural of Patronus here] appear to be very lifelike, but silver instead of their usual color. And because J.K.Rowling was one of the designers of Pottermore, I would trust Pottermore and say that they are pretty lifelike.